# Why doesn't my new circular saw run after the blade was installed?

Tags: circular-saw

My cordless Craftsman circular saw spun fine brand new out of the box. I put a blade on it and NOTHING... A light blinks and that's it. Anyone every dealt with this issue? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Go back to the box, look for the manual, read it. The "installing/changing a blade" and "troubleshooting" parts specifically.

Comment: Did you charge it up?

Comment: Can't tell more without model #. But it may have some sort of sensors that can detect when something is blocking proper operation, which a blade installed incorrectly could do.

Comment: It could have a safety feature, so read the manual

Answer (score 4):

The washer was put back on in reverse.

Comment: Please accept your answer to resolve this post.